# Firefox renders Bootstrap 3 `.form-inline` and text inputs wider than Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox

This applies to Bootstrap 3.3.7

I have the following markup - which is for a full width (`.container-fluid`) grey background, with a centered (`.container`) form:

The inline styles for the borders are for debugging purposes, but the outcome is the same if they are removed.

```
<div class="homepage-signup-insights container-fluid" style="border:1px solid red;">

<div class="container" style="border:1px solid orange;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">

            <form class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h3><b>Sign up for Newsletter</b></h3>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Company" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email" required>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send</button>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On Chrome  60.0.3112.113 it looks like this - which is how I want it:
[image]

In Firefox 55.0.3 it looks like this. As you can see there is more space on the left hand side of the text "sign up for newsletter". But I don't understand why because the markup is identical and there's no CSS or browser specific hacks:

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas why this is?

The Sass which is applied to `.homepage-signup-insights` is as follows. Removing this still gives the same bug (except it appears without the styling of course):

```
.homepage-signup-insights {
    background-color: #DEDEDE;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;

    .form-group {
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
    input[type="text"], input[type="email"] {
        border:0;
        border-radius: 0;
        background-color: #fff;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "solution" which I came up with to this was to apply a `max-width: 220px` to the CSS for the inputs:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="email"] {
    max-width: 220px;
    // ...
}
```

This is because I noticed using the Developer toolbar that Chrome gives the inputs (`.input-lg`) a width of 220px, whereas Firefox gives them a width of 308px. The additional width in Firefox causes things to go on to 2 separate lines.

I don't know if anyone has a better solution? Even if you give the inputs a `size=` attribute, Firefox renders them wider than Chrome. Very odd, and not something I'd expect in Bootstrap where it attempts to give cross browser consistency.